# What is the physical meaning of group velocity for elastic waves through crystals?

Tags: waves, crystals, phonons

In a chapter about phonons they define group speeds for elastic waves in crystals as the derivative of the dispersion relation:

$$v_g = \frac{d{\omega}}{d{k}} $$

I wonder though how they come to this equation, i.e. what is the physical meaning of $v_g$? 
I find on the internet information about the physical meaning about the group velocity of wave packets, but I don't see how I can interpret an elastic wave as a wave packet. So I hope someone can clarify the meaning of 'group velocity' for this particular case of elastic waves in a crystal.